# Desugaring rule for case expression within a do block.

Tags: haskell

I am reading [this](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.en.html) tutorial on Monad Transformers. It contains an example code where a case expression appears in a do block (as can be seen at the bottom in the picture below).

What is such a case expression desugared into ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`case` expressions in a `do` block are not desugared any more than they are outside of a `do` block. They are just an expression of type `Monad m => m a`.

Its very similar to an `if`, which is also not desugared.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think you want to say they need to be of type at least `Monad m => m a` to pass the type checker.  They can desugar to any type, but your program just may not type check.